# Position div to foot of container

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML page: https://jsfiddle.net/fk42dw85/

I'd like to position the orange block to the foot of the div container instead of the top. How do I achieve this?

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div style="background:url('https://dynaimage.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/q_auto,w_826,c_fill/http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.cnn.com%2Fcnnnext%2Fdam%2Fassets%2F131126191411-strahov-abbey-library.jpg');height:200px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="background:orange">
                        test
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using a `CSS` framework as `BootStrap` ?

Comment: Yes, I am using Bootstrap CSS Framework.

Comment: Are you able to restructure your HTML? is there a particular reason is done in that way? I'm asking since you might be able to make the image and the orange block siblings, that would make things much simpler

Comment: I would be happy to adjust. What would work best?

Comment: What you want then is an image with a footer, correct? let me take a look to your fiddle

Comment: as @R.DarioDuarte said can you restructure your HTML ? Or it must be that way ?

Comment: @ths Yes, I am happy to adjust my HTML :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this code https://jsfiddle.net/fk42dw85/97/

You can achieve that with:

```
 position: relative;
bottom: -175px;
```

Comment: One comment @Llazar, using bottom with a fixed value is very unpractical. If for some reason you need to change either the height of the orange box or the image itself, you also need to adjust this value. Have this in mind when using this solution

Comment: I totally agree with @R.DarioDuarte using fixed values isn't a wise choice.

Comment: You're right, fixed value is not the best solution but is a short solution with less code.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container {
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: calc(50% - 270px);
}
.parentContainer {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have margin-bottom which you can tweak around to get the right spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want an image with a footer related to it. I would suggest you to take the following approach, which is much simpler, let me know if that works for you.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image-footer">
    This is the footer of the image
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.image {
  background: url('https://dynaimage.cdn.cnn.com/cnn/q_auto,w_826,c_fill/http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.cnn.com%2Fcnnnext%2Fdam%2Fassets%2F131126191411-strahov-abbey-library.jpg');
  height:200px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image-footer {
  background: orange;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle modified with those changes: https://jsfiddle.net/rdarioduarte/fk42dw85/91/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution as well, which **avoids the use of absolute positioning**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 95%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

*Adjust the value of the top attribute* as you wish to get the desired effect.

Comment: Only downside is if I add more content: https://jsfiddle.net/fk42dw85/102/ Appreciate your efforts.